# How to Close CMD after starting an program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

I have wrote a batch file that opens two CMD windows in the folder I want so that I can run a server and type commands. I also want to be able to open firefox and sublime editor.

Everything works except I am left with 4 cmd windows not just the two I want.

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"
start cmd.exe /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"
cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"
start cmd.exe /K "firefox.exe"
cd "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\"
start cmd.exe /K "sublime_text.exe"
exit
```

I am running on Windows XP for my sins, so if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why starting a `cmd` just to start an `exe` instead of just starting the `exe`? Also be sure to know the difference between `cmd /k` and `cmd /c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"
start cmd.exe /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"
cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"
start firefox.exe
cd "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\"
start sublime_text.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"
start cmd /K "cd C:\xampp\htdocs\restful"

start  iexplore.exe
start  Safari.exe
exit
```

.

```
start "" "C:\users\YourUserName\Desktop\firefox.exe"
or
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\and Rest of the path"
```

<kbd>**Some examples:**</kbd>  [[ Link ]](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

```
START C:\MyFiles\Myletter.doc
::will open the file Myletter.doc in Word or WordPad 

START \\server\printer
::will ask if you want to install the printer, install the printer driver and then connect to the network printer

START C:\WINNT\System32\ssmarque.scr /C
::will open the configuration dialogue for the 3D text screen saver, whereas

START C:\WINNT\System32\ssmarque.scr /S
::will run the screen saver itself 

START http://www.googl.com
::will open Google's search page in your browser 

START mailto:president@whitehouse.gov
::will start your e-mail program with a message addressed to...?
```

Comment: Works for note pad, just not for firefox or sublime text, anything else you can suggest.

Comment: I don't have firefox but I tested on IE on win 7- see edit on post